# Computation of a mean (random sum)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, ... be independent and identially distributed positive random variables and define the sum $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n$. Consider the first time $N$ where $S_N \ge b$ with a given positive value $b$.

I need to compute (simplify) $E(NS_N)$. I need an expression in function of simple terms like $E(N)$, $E(X_1)$ etc... How proceed ? I'm not mastering the conditional mean.

Thank you

Comment: If $\mu=E(X_i)$, it's clear that $E(S_N) = N\cdot \mu$ (by the linearity of expectation).  Conversely, I would think that the expected $N$ at which $S_N$ passes a given $b$ is given by $\frac{b}{\mu}$, but I'm not sure how to show that this is the case through the definition of expectation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's not clear that $\mathbb{E}[S_N] = N\mu$ because $N$ is a random variable. Your left-hand side is a constant and right-hand side is random!!!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom "but I'm not sure how to show that this is the case through the definition of expectation", this result is simply the application of the Wald's equation. Compute $E(NS_N)$ is an other (maybe difficult, I don't know) problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**
Do you want to assume independence between $N$ and $X_i$? Then condition on $N$ and separate using independence.

Otherwise, you have to assume at least that $N$ is a stopping time with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra, generated by the $X_i$.

Now assume first that $X_i$ are 0-mean (eventually you will let $X_i = \mu + Y_i$ where $Y_i$ will be 0-mean, but for now assume $\mu=0$).

Now note that the stochastic process $\{S_n\}$ is a martingale, so $\mathbb{E}[S_N] = \mathbb{E}[S_t]$ for any $t$ (by Doob's lemma), in particular for $t=0$, and we know $\mathbb{E}[S_0]=0$.

I think you can argue similarly for the process $\{nS_n\}$, and then apply the construction with $Y_n$ to get your expected value.

To make that construction more formal, let $Y_i = X_i - \mu$ where $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X_1]$ so $\mathbb{E}[Y_1] = 0$ and now $Y_i$ are identical and 0-mean. Let $T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$. By the above logic it follows that $\mathbb{E}[N T_N] =0$. But
$$
N T_N = N \sum_{k=1}^N Y_i = N \sum_{k=1}^N (X_i - \mu) = NS_N - \mu N^2
$$
and taking expected values, note that the left-hand side becomes $\mathbb{E}[N T_N] =0$ and you can draw conclusions...

Comment: Thanks, in fact $N$ and the $X_i$ are not independent since we assume that $N$ is the stopping time corresponding to $min_N(S_N\ \textrm{s.t.}\ S_N \ge b)$.

Comment: Note that I've slightly edited my question for the fact that $S_N \ge b$.

Comment: Thanks you. I think that I have understood almost of your full proof. But I wonder why the condition on $N$ (the fact that $N$ depends on the value of the sequence $(X_i)$ for $i=1 \ldots N$ doesn't appear ?

Comment: What you call "the above logic" seems to fail since $\{nT_n\}$ is not a martingale. (If you are familiar with Brownian martingales, this is related to $(tB_t)$ not being a martingale.)

Comment: There is effectively a problem with the result $E(NS_n)=\mu E(N^2)$. Indeed we can use this one with the two first wald's equations to deduce the  Blackwell–Girshick formula. The problem is that this last formula is true only when $N$ is independent of the $X_i$.

Comment: @Did maybe we can divide by $N$ such that $T_N=\frac{NS_N-\mu N^2}{N}$. Then we apply $E(T_N)=0$ and in this case it follows that $E(\frac{NS_N-\mu N^2}{N})=0$. It's correct ?

Comment: So, it follows that $E(S_N)=\mu E(N)$, this does not help us in anything... Sorry for this mistake.

Comment: @Did You are right, $nT_n$ is not a martingale, only $T_n$ is... Need to modify this construction somehow, just not sure how off the top of my head.

Comment: Copying the Brownian case one sees that $\{R_n\}$ is a martingale, where $R_n=nT_n-\sum\limits_{k=1}^nT_k$.

Comment: @Did Thank you. So with your remark we have $E((N-1)S_N)=\mu E((N-1)N)$, and we can write $E(NS_N)=E(S_N)+\mu E(N^2)-\mu E(N)$. This is correct ? And this is true for a stopping time like the one described in my question ?

Comment: In fact we obtain the same result $E(NS_N)=\mu E(N^2)$. So the Blackwell–Girshick formula is true when $N$ depends of $X_i$ ?

Comment: You might want to explain in detail how these would be consequences of what you call my remark.

Comment: @Did I've applied $0=E(R_N)=E(NT_N-\sum_{k=1}^NT_k)=E((N-1)T_N)=E((N-1)\sum_{k=1}^N(X_k-\mu))=E((N-1)S_N-\mu N(N-1))$

Comment: Why the **third** equal sign?

Comment: I said that I've used your remark because I don't know anything about the Brownian nor Martingale theory.

Comment: "Why the third equal sign?"
This is a mistake sorry.

Comment: @Did maybe it's correct ? As I've said previously I don't know these notions. Maybe you can clarify if $U_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n}T_k$ is a martingale.

Comment: It is not. Try to show that $E[U_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n]=2U_n-U_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Did What do you suggest to compute $E(NS_N)$ in this case ?

Comment: In your case an overshoot is possible, that is, the event $[S_N\gt b]$ has positive probability, hence I see no reason to expect exact formulas. To get an idea of the literature, try to google variants of `overshoot` and `random walks`. Of course, if $X_k\leqslant x$ almost surely then $bN\leqslant NS_N\lt(b+x)N$ and bounds on $NS_N$ follow.

Comment: @Did Thank you. I've already noticed that we can bound in this way, but I would like an exact formula, not a bound.

Comment: Did you get that my last comment was an **im-** possibility result? I am beginning to wonder if you read carefully enough the comments written to help you.

Comment: @Did Yes I've read it, but does this really mean that an exact expression is impossible ? Maybe there exists an other approach. Look at this paper, [link](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=lingyun%20zhang%20stopped%20randomly&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F241688469_Variance_of_a_Randomly_Stopped_Sum%2Ffile%2F5046351ca1823c93fd.pdf&ei=p7PhUZnvIuiM7Qazj4CADw&usg=AFQjCNExG7sc2xtR3av_98KDp1b1ecfj3g&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZGU)

Comment: "This paper" is quite unrelated.

Comment: @Did Yes, the stopping rule isn't the same but it's in the same spirit...